# Update form from timer event handler

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer

I have a form (Form1) and this form has a `System.Timers.Timer` object. I'd like to Invalidate the form (Basically this is my goal, to Invalidate (call `Invalidate()`) the form every once in a while where timeout period changes each time when event is triggered). However since event handler method is static, I don't have access to instance of my form.

How can I pass some objects to my event handler?

Comment: Hi! Put your draft code here.

Comment: Well, just don't make it a static method then.  Make it an instance method of the form so you can use *this*.  The Timer class won't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple, the winforms timer is a component which means you can drag and drop a timer onto your form.  Use the properties grid to enable the time and set the timer interval.  Change the property grid to display the events and double click the tick event.  A new event handler will be created for you.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure you can use MS TPL. Start from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx)

```
Task formManager;
 private void FormManagerUpdateUI()
        {
            // ... UI update work here ... 
        }

        private void StartFormManager()
        {
            formManager = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { /* You validation code goes here */ }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
            formManager.ContinueWith((t) => { FormManagerUpdateUI(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
        }
```